# Computing a slightly different matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to find the best way to compute the minimum element wise products between two sets of vectors. The usual matrix multiplication `C=A@B` computes `Cij` as the sum of the pairwise products of the elements of the vectors `Ai` and `B^Tj`. I would like to perform instead the minimum of the pairwise products. I can't find an efficient way to do this between two matrices with numpy.

One way to achieve this would be to generate the 3D matrix of the pairwise products between `A` and `B` (before the sum) and then take the minimum over the third dimension. But this would lead to a huge memory footprint (and I actually dn't know how to do this).

Do you have any idea how I could achieve this operation ?

**Example:**

```
A = [[1,1],[1,1]]
B = [[0,2],[2,1]]
```

matrix matmul:

`C = [[1*0+1*2,1*2+1*1][1*0+1*2,1*2+1*1]] = [[2,3],[2,3]]`

minimum matmul:

`C = [[min(1*0,1*2),min(1*2,1*1)][min(1*0,1*2),min(1*2,1*1)]] = [[0,1],[0,1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after extending `A` to `3D`  -

```
A = np.asarray(A)
B = np.asarray(B)
C_out = np.min(A[:,None]*B,axis=2)
```

If you care about memory footprint, use [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/doc/user_guide.rst#enabling-intel-vml-support) to be efficient about it -

```
import numexpr as ne

C_out = ne.evaluate('min(A3D*B,2)',{'A3D':A[:,None]})
```

Timings on large arrays -

```
In [12]: A = np.random.rand(200,200)

In [13]: B = np.random.rand(200,200)

In [14]: %timeit np.min(A[:,None]*B,axis=2)
34.4 ms ± 614 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit ne.evaluate('min(A3D*B,2)',{'A3D':A[:,None]})
29.3 ms ± 316 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [16]: A = np.random.rand(300,300)

In [17]: B = np.random.rand(300,300)

In [18]: %timeit np.min(A[:,None]*B,axis=2)
113 ms ± 2.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit ne.evaluate('min(A3D*B,2)',{'A3D':A[:,None]})
102 ms ± 691 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So, there's some improvement with `numexpr`, but maybe not as much I was expecting it to be.

Comment: Nice, could you elaborate on the numexpr module ? The doc isn't really helpful. Does it mean that the expression will be evaluated by computing the minimum for each pair of vectors without storing the actual pairwise products ?

Comment: @debzsud I am not aware of the exact internal implementation of it, but from the docs it states that it makes use of multi-cores and from the benchmarking off the previous solutions with it, I have seen it to be really good on performance on large arrays and that most certainly should be with the memory efficiency.

Comment: @Divakar  Did you observe any use of multi-cores in this example?

Comment: @max9111 Added timings and conclusion. A memory profiler could clarify things further.

Comment: By any chance, do you know how to apply the broadcasting version (first version) with A and B being scipy.sparse.csr_matrix instances ?

Comment: @debzsud SciPy sparse matrices don't support 3D, which we are doing here. So, it won't work with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Numba can be also an option**

I was a bit surprised of the not particularly good Numexpr Timings, so I tried a Numba Version. For large Arrays this can be optimized further. (Quite the same principles like for a dgemm can be applied)

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import numexpr as ne

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def min_pairwise_prod(A,B):
    assert A.shape[1]==B.shape[1]
    res=np.empty((A.shape[0],B.shape[0]))

    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B.shape[0]):
            min_prod=A[i,0]*B[j,0]
            for k in range(B.shape[1]):
                prod=A[i,k]*B[j,k]
                if prod<min_prod:
                    min_prod=prod
            res[i,j]=min_prod
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
A=np.random.rand(300,300)
B=np.random.rand(300,300)

%timeit res_1=min_pairwise_prod(A,B) #parallel=True
5.56 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_1=min_pairwise_prod(A,B) #parallel=False
26 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit res_2 = ne.evaluate('min(A3D*B,2)',{'A3D':A[:,None]})
87.7 ms ± 265 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit res_3=np.min(A[:,None]*B,axis=2)
110 ms ± 214 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

A=np.random.rand(1000,300)
B=np.random.rand(1000,300)
%timeit res_1=min_pairwise_prod(A,B) #parallel=True
50.6 ms ± 401 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_1=min_pairwise_prod(A,B) #parallel=False
296 ms ± 5.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_2 = ne.evaluate('min(A3D*B,2)',{'A3D':A[:,None]})
992 ms ± 7.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit res_3=np.min(A[:,None]*B,axis=2)
1.27 s ± 15.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```